# Vacation Destination

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, computer-puzzle

So, a while ago I asked a friend to plan our next vacation. I had to tear him away from his computer and this site to get him to do anything. Which was probably my first mistake. I don't know if he is trying to get even or is actually excited about this vacation.

Anyway, he emailed me this list and said see you there. I have no idea what any of this means, so I went to talk with him (he was only in the other room) but all he kept mumbling about was ordered lists and strings inside of strings. I don't know if its important or if he finally cracked.

> 4)  Waiter
>   7)  End
>   9)  Pause
>   3)  VMD title
>   5)  Fast feathered swimmer
>   2)  Wait in line
>   8)  Ancient
>   6)  Transformation process
>   1)  No pattern
>
> 7)  Instructions
>   6)  Long lived
>   3)  Aromatic leaf
>   1)  Blue box
>   2)  An arrangement
>   4)  Binary single character
>   8)  Contains pictures
>   5)  Small bite
>
> 4)  Information
>   2)  Non-standard layout
>   6)  Home Sweet Home
>   1)  Nothing
>   3)  Magical root
>   5)  Multipurpose tool
>
> 3)  Exterminate
>   8)  Set aside
>   5)  Pile up
>   2)  Coffee
>   6)  Unknown
>   7)  Rules
>   1)  A hat
>   4)  A friend and an enemy
>
> Once you're finished with the list don't forget to cross your I's and dot your T's

**What city does he have in mind for our vacation?**

---

> My friend is a programmer by trade, but he eat, sleeps, and dreams code anyway. He also likes British science fiction.

Comment: Can I ask, are there definitely eight clues in the last set or should there be nine? I have a hunch but I may be chasing shadows.

Comment: @hexomino Definitely eight

Comment: @Neon612 I'm in need of a hint.

Comment: @PaulBeckingham Hint added

Comment: Feels like a really long crossword puzzle.

Answer (score 6):

No answer yet but perhaps a way to proceed...

> It seems like each phrase can be represented as a different word - blue box, for example, is tardis. Tardis has both a t and an i in it so I feel like that's on the right track. I suspect after finding all of the words, you would replace the i's by <del>dashes</del> ones and the t's by <del>dots</del> zeros, place each list in numerical order and then decipher the <del>morse code</del> binary.

Comment: You are half right.

Comment: It sounds good, but I'm not sure how it incorporates the number to the left.

Comment: Still only half right

Answer (score 3):

**NEW ATTEMPT**

I'm guessing that the answer to each clue must contain

> the letter **I** and the letter **T**.

So some attempts at the clues are below.

**SET 1**

> 4) Waiter = *hesitater* (*loiterer* or *maitre d'*)
>  7) End = *terminate*
>  9) Pause = *interrupt*? (or *intermission* or *interlude*?)
>  3) VMD title = *veterinarian*
>  5) Fast feathered swimmer = *gentoo penguin*
>  2) Wait in line = *loiter*
>  8) Ancient = *prehistoric* (or *primitive*)
>  6) Transformation process = *mutation*
>  1) No pattern = *arbitrary* (or *erratic*)

Perhaps instead of using the clue numbers to reorder the clue's answers, we instead use those numbers to

> take the corresponding letter from each correct answer.
>
>  So if a clue is numbered 4, take the 4th letter.  Unfortunately, at the moment for the first set above that gives me: **[I/T] A [T/S/E] T O O? [O/V] I [A/E]**
>
>  I can't really make sense of that, so maybe that use of the numbering isn't correct.

**SET 2**

> 7) Instructions = *directions*
>  6) Long lived = *ancient*?
>  3) Aromatic leaf = *cilantro*?
>  1) Blue box = *Tardis*
>  2) An arrangement = *?*
>  4) Binary single character = *bit*
>  8) Contains pictures = *illustrated*
>  5) Small bite = *appetizer*?

---

**OLD ATTEMPT VERIFIED WRONG**

Based on Morgan G's idea, I took a crack at the first set.  Nothing definitive, but perhaps if you squint you can see

> **New York**?

Because if you

> Reorder them by their number, then figure out a word for each, then take every letter **i** in the answer to be a morse code dash and every **t** to be a dot...
>
>  1) No pattern = *arbitrary* → -. → **N**
>  2) Wait in line = *stand* → . → **E**
>  3) VMD title = *veterinarian* →  .-- →  **W**
>  4) Waiter (server?)
>  5) Fast feathered swimmer (gentoo) penguin .- or - = A or T??
>  6) Transformation process (mutation would yield U...)
>  7) End = *terminate* → .-. →  **R**
>  8) Ancient = *prehistoric* → -.- →  **K**
>  9) Pause (break?)

The trouble is that

> if this is the correct approach, there are many possible answers to almost every clue, and thus it's hard to definitively answer this.

Comment: You have the second part correct. The I & T part is not needed for the words.

Comment: this is very old, but arrangement could be presentation or disposition?